# SDL2 stucks in SDL_RenderClear()

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, sdl-2

I have two files, one is main file (main.cpp) other one is for multi-threading (threads.cpp).
I use **SDL_PushEvent(**) in threads.cpp and **SDL_PollEvent()** in main.cpp.
Below is a logic of my sample code.

**main.cpp**

```
bool Init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        return false;

    SDL_DisplayMode mode;
    SDL_GetDisplayMode(0, 0, &mode);
    this->win_width = mode.w;
    this->win_height = mode.h;

    this->win = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, 0, 0, win_width, win_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (this->win == NULL) {
        LOGE("[Init] SDL Window Created failed : %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (this->renderer == NULL) {
        LOGE("[Init] SDL Renderer Created failed : %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    this->bmp = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB565, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, win_width, win_height);
    if (this->bmp == NULL) {
        LOGE("[Init] SDL Texture Created failed : %s", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void DisplayEvent (SDL_Event e) {
    FrameObject obj = *(FrameObject*) e.user.data1;

    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = rect.y = 0;
    rect.w = obj.frameWidth;
    rect.h = obj.frameHeight;

    int r = SDL_UpdateTexture(this->bmp, NULL, obj.FrameData.RGB, rect.w*2);
    LOGI("[DisplayEvent] - UpdateTexture");

    // Reneder this Frame
    SDL_RenderClear(this->renderer);
    LOGI("[DisplayEvent] - RenderClear");
    SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, this->bmp, NULL, &rect);
    LOGI("[DisplayEvent] - RenderCopy");
    SDL_RenderPresent(this->renderer);
    LOGI("[DisplayEvent] - RenderPresent");
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    Init();

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event e;
        // Event Polling
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            switch (e.type) {
                case MY_EVENT:
                    LOGI("[main] - Get MY_EVENT");
                    DisplayEvent(e);
                    LOGI("[main] - %s more MY_EVENT", SDL_HasEvent(MY_EVENT) ? "Has" : "Hasn't");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**threads.cpp**

```
void* push_event(void *arg) {
    FrameObject obj = (FrameObject*) arg;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_zero(event);
        event.type = MY_EVENT;
        event.user.data1 = obj;
        event.user.data2 = 0;
        if (SDL_PushEvent(&event) == 1) LOGI("[push_event] - Push MY_EVENT");
        else LOGE("[push_event] - Event Push Error : %s", SDL_GetError());

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** 
I add more sample code. I found the problem is not missing the SDL Event. The problem is SDL thread (main Thread) is blocked at SDL_RenderClear().

The log message output **"[DisplayEvent] - UpdateTexture"** but not print **"[DisplayEvent] - RenderClear"**. It's weird. For create single thread to run push_event is find, but when I create two threads to run push_event, the SDL Thread is blocked.

Dost it problem is hardware i.e. GPU?

Answer (score 0):

SDL Wiki on [SDL_PushEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) says that it is thread-safe so I'm assuming it is Ok to call it from other threads. However, it says there that you need first to call `SDL_RegisterEvents` to get an event ID suitable for using as application specific events, and then use it to push your events.

This is not clear from your code, are you calling `SDL_RegisterEvents`? This might be the problem. Also, have you checked if it works if you push the event on the same thread you initialized the video? This test will make sure the problem isn't related to threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the problem is not missing event. I also update the question. The problem is SDL is blocked.